# Alternate address to access https://accounts.google.com

Tags: google-account

We use Google services to sign on to a range of Web Applications as contractors for a company. But they have locked this address and state that this address enables file sharing - which I'm pretty sure it doesn't, it just enables you to login to another service that allows file sharing such as Google drive or Gmail. They previously had drive and Gmail locked, so I don't have a problem with that. But we chose the remaining application we use for timesheets etc based on them providing Google sign in.

Probably a ridiculous question, but is there any other to authenticate to Google?

Answer (score 1):

As an end-user, you should not worry about a specific URL to sign in to a Google account. Any web app that requires you to be authorized will show a page telling you if you have to sign in or request access and will give you the option to switch accounts. However, the company might set rules about the single sign-on solution to be used, but again, this is not something that, as an end-user, you should worry about, as the sign-in flow should point you through the processes.

#### Related

- [How do I access the Google login page for a non-SSO account, if an SSO IDP is redirecting me?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/130952/88163)

#### Reference

- [Sign in with Google](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/12849458?hl=en)
- [Drive and Sites firewall and proxy settings](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2589954?hl=en)

Comment: I expect this is a network filtering  (firewall) issue not related to anything Google.  They are likely  connecting to the network as part of their work. They are trying to circumvent that company's controls.   It shouldn't be a big deal if they are simply a SOHO but if they are a larger org it may be unwise to mess around.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a 3rd party IdP like Okta, OneLogin, JumpCloud, etc.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/60224

Comment: The referred article is related to G Suite accounts, not to Google common accounts.

Comment: Yes, it was stated "as contractors for a company" so why would this not be G Suite accounts? Also if the restriction is being applied to personal Google accounts then the limitations are being limited by the companies device or network policies. Solution: use your own device and/or network.

Comment: This is probably worth a try. I'll get the tech guys at the company to see if this alternative will work. If it redirects straight to the 3rd party without going through  accounts.google.com, then it is a possibility.