# How do I access the Google login page for a non-SSO account, if an SSO IDP is redirecting me?

Tags: google-account, login, google-multi-login

I have a work Google account and a personal Google account.  The work Google account uses a SAML identity provider (like Auth0, Okta, OneLogin, etc).  The personal Google account is just a regular non-gsuite gmail.com thing.

Sometimes, I'll want to log in to my personal account on a device which has previously logged in to one of my work accounts, and it will unconditionally redirect me to the SAML IdP page.  I can't access my personal account until I log in to my work account.  This is true even if I navigate directly to accounts.google.com.

I can manually zap the cookies for google.com in my browser to force it to not know who I am, but is there some way that that I can tell Google "please give me the multi-account chooser"?  Some URL I can navigate to which will always do that, and not redirect me?

Comment: I suggest instead using the profile feature of your browser.

Comment: For the purposes of this question, let’s assume I use Safari which does not have profiles.

Comment: +1 - I have this exact issue and have had for years. It's hard to search for solutions as all the keywords return more common SSO issues. Once you're logged in, Google's multi-account behaviour is class leading - so it's really frustrating. Eg at Christmas, when I don't want to log into work, with it's complicated MFA, just to then log into my personal gmail afterwards.

Comment: This gets better. Browsing to https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser brings up the account picker, I can chose my personal account, and I get redirected to a myaccount.google.com page, but the session is not really valid. So if I then chose an app like gmail (from the top-right "9 dots" menu) - it prompts me to login - by redirecting me to my Work SSO (as in _not_ the account I just picked!) :rage:

Comment: I also have this problem and would love an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Andrew M's comment, I think what you can do is log in to the personal account from accounts.google.com/AccountChooser . Then you should end up in the account page but both sessions are "Expired." If you hit the top right profile icon and sign out of all accounts then it should stop redirecting you to SSO.

Comment: I don't know if the behavior @AndrewM observed was simply a bug that they've since fixed, but at least in the testing that I've been able to do today, https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser is indeed the correct move here.

Comment: This worked for me, but you need to first select a non-SSO account from the chooser and then you can click the top-right profile icon to sign out of all accounts.